# Webscraping html table using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, api, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
global browser
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
s = Service('''C:\\Users\\rajes\\yogita\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe''')
browser = webdriver.Chrome('''C:\\Users\\rajes\\yogita\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe''')
time.sleep(2)
url = 'https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/en/tools/finder-tools/bonds/?dateIssue.min=2022-09-30&dateIssue.max=2022-09-30'
browser.get(url)
browser.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/aside/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]'))).click()
browser.implicitly_wait(20)
time.sleep(10)
Stuttgart_links = []
wkn_code = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="tablesaw-317"]/tbody/tr[2]').text
print(wkn_code)
```

Objective of this job :
I am trying to scrape bonds for given date range(30/9/2022) in
url : https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/en/tools/finder-tools/bonds/?dateIssue.min=2022-09-30&dateIssue.max=2022-09-30

There are 3 bonds on this date range, I need WKN from this list (A3K94C,LB381Q, A3K91M)

My approach :

I have tried Selenium approach as I was not able to get HTML table using Beautifulsoup and request method

Problem I am facing :
I am getting NoSuchElementException error on it
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="tablesaw-317"]/tbody/tr[2]"}

Help I needed :
I want to understand why it is not taking XPATH for those WKN, as I go at Inspect on Chrome Devtools table is there but when chrome is open as per Selenium then there is no table.

I would like to know what is right approach to scrape data for this website.
Any help would be appreciated to guide me in right direction.As I am new to Python so tried ways I know through tutorials but no help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the table element and then use `get_attribute("outerHTML")`

Then use `pd.read_html()`

```
browser.get("https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/en/tools/finder-tools/bonds/?dateIssue.min=2022-09-30&dateIssue.max=2022-09-30")
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/aside/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]'))).click()
table=WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table[id^='tablesaw']"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
df=pd.read_html(table)[0]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      WKN  ...                                       Actions
0  A3K94C  ...  Aktionen  Add to watchlist  Add to Portfolio
1  LB381Q  ...  Aktionen  Add to watchlist  Add to Portfolio
2  A3K91M  ...  Aktionen  Add to watchlist  Add to Portfolio

[3 rows x 9 columns]
```